# Create Perl array without the use of curly brackets so that array is not confined to specific block

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop

I want to maintain an array outside of a block of code. The array that I am interested in is @csv2years. This is currently within a set of curly brackets which contain the code for a `for` loop. I realise I somehow need to rearrange this so that the curly brackets do not contain the conditions which create the array. I don't know how to specifically reference csv2 without the `for { }` section.

```
#!/bin/perl
# creates subroutines for discovering year

sub find_year {
   my ( $str ) = @_;
   my $year;
   $year = $1 if( $str =~ /\b((?:19|20)\d\d)\b/ );
   return $year
}

#####CREATE CSV2 DATA

my @csv2 = (); # Creates new empty array @csv2

open CSV2, "<csv2" or die; # Creates the file handle CSV2, inputs the data from csv2 into CVS2

@csv2=<CSV2>; # populates @csv2 array with data from file handle CSV2
close CSV2;

my %csv2hash = ();  # Creates empty hash csv2hash

for (@csv2) {            # for data in @csv2 array
    chomp;
    my ($title) = $_ =~ /^.+?,\s*([^,]+?),/; #/define the data which is the title

    #Indicate that title data will input into csv2hash

    $csv2hash{$_} = $title;
    #Create a hash for find year of csv2
    my %csv2_year = find_year($title);

    my @csv2years = keys(%csv2_year);
    print "@csv2years\n";
}
```

The above code currently prints out @csv2years, but if the `print "@csv2years\n";` is placed outside of the curly brackets, nothing is printed out. How can I rearrange this code so that there is no need for the for loop and/or curly brackets?

Here is the csv2 data:

```
14564564,1989 the door to the others,546456,47878787
456456445,the Twin Peaks theory project 1979,45454545,45454545
456456445,the Twin Peaks forget that,45454545,45454545
454654564, 1969 hello good world your great ,45456456, 54564654
```

The output of `print "@csv2years\n";` is :

```
1989
1979

1969
```

Comment: If you want `@csv2years` to be accessible outside the block, you'll need to declare it (`my @csv2years;`) outside the block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your immediate need:

```
my @csv2years;
for ( @csv2 ) {
    ...
    push @csv2years, find_year($title);
}
print "$_\n" for @csv2years;
```

But there are a ton of improvements that will help you up your Perl-fu. A few of the salient ones are:

- `use strict; use warnings;`
- use a dedicated CSV parser like `Text::CSV`
- iterate over the file line by line instead of cramming everything into an array and then loop over each element
- replace bareword filehandles with lexical ones (`open my $fh, ...`)
- assign a default value in case `find_year` doesn't find a year (empty string, perhaps?)
- assign the result of `find_year` to a scalar instead of a hash

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you explain the "push" part?

Comment: @nmh `push` adds on an element to the end of an array. In the example above, the result of the subroutine is added for every loop iteration